# DIV Layer in Fieldset opens in background in place of foreground

Tags: html, css, input, fieldset

I have implemented an jquery datepicker for an input field in html. Problem is, that the datepicker appears in the background in place of in the foreground and so I cannot set a date (see the link). The div tag of the input field is in an fieldset which is always in the front.

http://i40.tinypic.com/35i1wl0.png

what can I do to let the datepicker open in the front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problems with positioning or z-index property

I think that your divs simple have a more z-index value that jquery datepicker div.

Try change yours z-index property. Often z-index sets to much bigger values like 9999 or 999 it's not correct, because for you it is sufficient to use the lower values of z-index property.

Comment: to change the z-index of the datepicker I have to set it in the css for the input field?

Comment: No. I just talk about changing of your div z-index property. If you wonna change datepicker z-index, you can see the class or id of datepicker div from firebug or google chrome dev tools. For example, on one of my sites datepicker has this id = "ui-datepicker-div". You need to add additional css styles like #ui-datepicker-div {z-index: 9999 }

Comment: hm... can you post your code somewhere? May be on your own hosting or jsfiddle or something else

Comment: I get it! I have defined the style in another css file I was thinking

Answer (score 0):

Try z-index property to datepicker open in the front like

```
z-index:999;
```